# Isn't the sentence "Não tem ninguém" redundant or even incorrect? (É a frase "não tem ninguém" redudante ou até mesmo incorreta?)

Tags: uso-de-palavras, coloquialismos, concordância-negativa

**[English]**

In English we say:

> There is nobody in the room

Meanwhile, in Portuguese I'm used to see:

> Não tem ninguém na sala

Which sounds completely redundant.

Is that correct to say so or is it a common sense that this is considered correct although technically it is not?

---

**[Português]**

Em inglês dizemos:

> There is nobody in the room. (Tem ninguém na sala.)

Enquanto que, em português, estou acostumado a ver:

> Não tem ninguém na sala

Que soa completamente redundante.

É correto dizer isso, ou é um senso comum de que isso é considerado correto apesar de tecnicamente não ser?

Comment: Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84034/app-executa-no-emulador-mas-n%C3%A3o-aparece-%C3%ADcone) um caso de dupla negação que não é aceito pela norma culta, mas ocorre com alguma frequência: *(...) nem no emulador e nem quando gero um apk e instalo no celular o ícone não aparece (...)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[English]**

Does it really sound redundant, or is it just you trying to normalize the language? Natural languages are not as regular as us programmers would like them to be!

Every language has pleonasms like that, and a gray zone of expressions which are more or less frowned upon (like *elo de ligação*). *Não tem ninguém* is a pretty common pleonasm that has become part of the language.

---

**[Português]**

Realmente soa redundante, ou é apenas você tentando normalizar a língua? Línguas naturais não são tão regulares quanto nós programadores gostaríamos que fossem!

Toda língua tem pleonasmos assim, e uma zona incerta de expressões que são meio desaprovadas (como *elo de ligação*). *Não tem ninguém* é um pleonasmo um tanto comum que virou parte da língua.

Comment: It sounded redundant for me for a long time (perhaps for the fact I'm a programmer, by nature), until the day I accepted that, but I never knew the origin and motivation of that expression, that's why I decided to ask now that I have a chance to have a good insight of that :)

Comment: Well I consider myself a programmer too but this kind of redundancy sounds very natural to me, because it's very common in my native language (Czech). Actually, even after many years, I still struggle with not using it in English!

Comment: btw @Math - I am really happy to see you here :)) despite the fact you just made me doubt whether I am a programmer (by nature) hahaha

Comment: @MichalMau happy to see you here too, you as an enthusiastic could not  be missing here. Perhaps my sentence is not what defines who is programmer or not, maybe this is just the definition for very very picky people :)

Comment: I would avoid stating that we are a community of mostly programmers. They are not the target audience of the site.

Comment: @E_net4 I didn't mean that we are, I meant the OP is (I know him from pt.SO).

Answer (score 13):

**[English]**

Actually, at least in Brazil, no. It is a "feature" of the language, a way that feels natural.

As pointed by bfavaretto, natural languages are different than programming ones.

In Japanese, for instance, if a question is asked in a negative way, a confirmation means confirming the negative, whereas in (Brazilian) Portuguese you are usually expected to ignore the negative in the question. To give an example:

> Não tem ninguém na sala?

or

> Is there nobody in the room?

In Japanese, a "Yes" means that there are no people in the room, unquestionably, and "No" means there are people, while both in English and Portuguese a simple "Yes" or "No" may be seen as too dubious to what it means.

In brazilian portuguese, usually people will ignore the negative and give a "longer answer" to account for confusions, saying "Não, não tem ninguém" ("No, there isn't anybody") or "Sim, tem gente lá" ("Yes, there are people in there").

This is Cultural, and related to how the language has evolved and really rooted in how people speak and write.

---

**[Português]**

Na verdade, pelo menos no Brasil, não. Essa é uma "característica" da língua, um jeito que soa natural.

Como apontado pelo bfavaretto, linguagens naturais são diferentes das de programação.

Em japonês, por exemplo, se uma pergunta é feita de modo negativo, uma confirmação significa confirmar a negativa, enquanto que no português (brasileiro) você é geralmente esperado a ignorar a negativa nessa pergunta.
Para dar um exemplo:

> Não tem ninguém na sala?

Em japonês, um "sim" significa que não há pessoas na sala, inquestionavelmente, e "não" significa que há pessoas, enquanto que ambos em inglês e português um simples "sim" ou "não" pode ser visto como muito ambíguo ao que se quer dizer.

No português brasileiro, geralmente as pessoas ignorarão a negativa e darão uma resposta "mais longa" para evitar confusões, dizendo "Não, não tem ninguém" ou "Sim, tem gente lá".

Isso é cultural, e relacionado a como a língua evoluiu e realmente se enraizou em como as pessoas falam e escrevem.

Answer (score 5):

**[English]**

This would be incorrect in English, because there's a grammar rule which clearly says so - the disallowance of double negatives. In Portuguese, however, we have no such rule and this sentence is, thus, perfectly fine.

I will also add that, in Portugal, it's more common to say "Não *há* ninguém" or "Não *está* ninguém". This seems more correct to, and it is the properest translation of *to be*: ser/estar.

---

**[Português]**

Isso estaria incorreto em inglês, porque há uma regra de gramática que claramente diz isso - a rejeição de negativas duplas. Em português, porém, não temos tal regra e essa frase é, desse modo, perfeitamente correta.

Também acrescento que, em Portugal, é mais comum dizer "Não *há* ninguém" ou "Não *está* ninguém". Dessa forma parece mais correto, e essa é a tradução mais apropriada do inglês *to be*.