# "Não tem nada" é correto?

Tags: concordância-negativa

É muito comum se ouvir, pelo menos no Brasil, "não tem nada", "não tem ninguém", "não sabe nada", etc., mas seria gramaticalmente correto dizer isso?

Porque, pela lógica, se não tem ninguém, então tem alguém, e se não tem nada, então tem algo, se considerar "ninguém" e "nada" um objeto/elemento ao invés de um conceito/ideia.

Na lógica de programação seria algo como:

```
if (!ninguém) alert("Há alguém");
```

Em inglês, é incorreto dizer "there isn't nothing", se o sentido da frase é negativo, sendo correto apenas "there isn't anything". Assim como em português temos o "não há coisa alguma".

Mas tem um correto? Ou é apenas questão de qual achar melhor?

Comment: Relacionada (ou duplicata?): http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/242/isnt-the-sentence-não-tem-ninguém-redundant-or-even-incorrect

Comment: @bfavaretto Nossa, verdade. Eu sabia que já tinha visto uma pergunta dessa por aqui, mas não tinha certeza. Eu até pesquisei por essa pergunta aqui mas não achei nada, então decidi perguntar. Apago a minha ou deixo pra ser fechada como duplicata?

Comment: Você não vai poder apagar, porque já tem resposta votada. Fechar como duplicata é uma boa solução, assim quem achar esta pergunta chega na outra. Posteriormente os moderadores podem optar por mesclar as duas.

Comment: @bfavaretto Então aí teria que adicionar uma tradução na resposta aceita ou na mais votada da outra pergunta, pra que uma pessoa que só fale português possa ter acesso à resposta.

Comment: Essa é uma boa discussão para o [meta]: devemos manter abertas duplicatas escritas em línguas diferentes?

Comment: @bfavaretto Então, mas [já até foi discutido sobre isso](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/36/should-similar-questions-written-in-different-languages-be-marked-as-duplicate). A resposta mais votada foi que elas devem ser fechadas independente do idioma em que estão, mas que devem ser adicionadas traduções para as respostas e a pergunta da pergunta referenciada.

Comment: É mesmo, eu tinha esquecido dessa discussão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno,  essas expressões, conforme você afirma, são muito comuns no Brasil, no Português falado e também no escrito. O uso realmente é disseminado e **linguistas descritivos consideram perfeitamente aceitável essa forma de se expressar**. Até mesmo porque a gramática normativa não oferece outra forma mais direta e mais clara de dizer "não há nada", "não foi nada" ou "não tem nada"  (Não há coisa alguma? Não foi coisa alguma? NÃO). Cito [Oswald de Andrade](http://brainly.com.br/tarefa/1494934):

Dê-me um cigarro
Diz a gramática
Do professor
E do mulato sabido
Mas o bom negro e o bom branco
Da nação brasileira
Dizem todos os dias
Deixa disso camarada
Me dá um cigarro.