# O uso de dupla negação é correto semanticamente?

Tags: significado, português-europeu

Ouço seguidamente em conversas informais (em pt-BR) frases onde há o uso do *não*, seguido de uma palavra que indica a ausência daquilo que se está perguntando. Exemplificando:

```
- Tens algum dinheiro para me emprestar?
- Não tenho nenhum Real no bolso.
```

Ou ao chegar ao local de uma comemoração:

```
- Bom dia, os outros convidados já chegaram?
- Não chegou ninguém até agora!
```

Outro exemplo é o título [deste livro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LFTCMJM) (de Agatha Christie) que se chama "E não sobrou nenhum".

Fico com a impressão de que ao dizer, p.ex., que **não** tenho **nenhum** Real no bolso, isto implica que eu tenha dinheiro, já que o que não tenho é nenhum.

Não sei se estas frases são típicas do Brasil ou se ocorrem em Portugal (ocorrem ?), mas elas não me parecem semanticamente corretas. Ainda que possam ser ditas de maneira diferente ("não tenho Real algum no bolso") o uso desta dupla negação é bastante comum por aqui.

Em resumo, as frases dadas como exemplo acima significam o que pretendem significar, ou exatamente seu oposto? De bônus, elas são usadas em pt-PT?

Comment: Vê estas perguntas: [«não tem ninguém» é redundante ou incorreto?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/242/isnt-the-sentence-n%C3%A3o-tem-ningu%C3%A9m-redundant-or-even-incorrect-%C3%89-a-frase-n%C3%A3) e [«não tem nada» é correto?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/964/n%C3%A3o-tem-nada-%C3%A9-correto) A segunda foi fechada como duplicata da primeira.

Comment: E sim, é assim que se fala em Portugal também.

Comment: @Jacinto Não havia localizado estas perguntas antes! Eu tinha pesquisado por "negação" e não cheguei nelas! Podemos iniciar o procedimento de marcá-las como duplicatas...

Comment: Eu tinha uma vaga ideia de ter visto uma pergunta deste tipo, e após várias tentativas encontrei-a. Não tens maneira de tornar a pergunta suficientemente diferente das outras? Um aspecto não coberto pelas outras? Tou a pensar que não sei se sempre se usou a dupla negação no português ou se surgiu numa época recente.

Comment: @Jacinto É preciso recuar ao latim clássico para deixar de encontrar este tipo de construção. Hoje em dia está até relativamente enfraquecida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Não chegou ninguém até agora!* significa que o conjunto de pessoas que chegaram é vazio.

O português permite casos de verdadeira dupla negação — do tipo proposicional, em que as duas negações se anulam —, mas este não é um deles. Um exemplo de verdadeira dupla negação seria:

> Os convidados não deixaram de chegar. [ou seja, chegaram]

As frases que dás não são «semanticamente incorretas» porque o pronome indefinido negativo pós-verbal *ninguém* não tem valor negativo. Este tipo de «dupla negação» é por vezes chamado de *concordância negativa* (*Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian, vol. I, pág. 491):

> [E]m português, as expressões que entram em concordância negativa com um operador negativo que as legitima têm um valor real positivo (que é sempre um valor de igualdade ou de superioridade) e [] a forma negativa (concordante) que essas expressões assumem funciona como um indicador de que está presente na posição adequada um operador de negação que nega tal valor positivo.

Repara que a frase equivale a esta:

> Não é verdade que tenha chegado **alguém** até agora.

Simplesmente substituir *ninguém* por *alguém* na frase original não é possível, mas por razões ligadas à interpretação de *alguém* nesse contexto (*Não chegou alguém* refere-se a alguém em particular). Esta correspondência é mais evidente em construções em que *alguém* e *ninguém* variam livremente:

> Ainda não vi **ninguém**/**alguém** que tivesse chegado.

Para mais informação, incluindo uma abordagem história e comparação com outras línguas, vê o artigo [*Aspectos da negação na história das línguas românicas*](https://web.archive.org/web/20160609065044/http://www.apl.org.pt/docs/actas-12-encontro-apl-1996_vol2.pdf) (1997) de Ana Maria Martins (pág. 179). Em fases anteriores da língua, frases como *ninguém não chegou* e *dirá ser impossível ninguém [=alguém] poder vencer o rei* eram possíveis. A autora explica-o como uma evolução em português dos indefinidos negativos de itens de polaridade fraca (legitimados em contextos negativos e modais) para itens de polaridade forte (apenas contextos negativos) e define estes tipos polaridade em função da existência de uma subespecificação variável.

Answer (score 2):

Embora uma análise semântica possa concluir que esse tipo de contrução gramatical não faz sentido porque há uma dupla negação, é assim que se fala em todo o Brasil. Dizer "Tenho nenhum Real no bolso" pode até ser compreendido, mas "Não tenho algum Real no bolso" soa muito estranho e pode deixar um ouvinte confuso.  Da mesma forma, "Chegou ninguém até agora" será compreendido, enquanto "Não chegou alguém até agora" não é idiomático.

Sim, nós brasileiros usamos muito esse tipo de construção gramatical.

> - "Não, não tem nada aqui."
> - "Não vi ninguém na rua."
> - "Nunca ouvi nada a respeito."

Contudo, em outros contextos, em frases interrogativas, é idiomático e ouve-se frequentemente frases do tipo:

> - "Não tinha alguém esperando por você?"
> - "Não tinhas algum dinheiro na poupança?"

Answer (score 1):

Gramaticalmente seriam possíveis também esses dois tipos de construções:

> Eu não comprei bala alguma. *ou*
>   Eu não comprei nenhuma bala.

No português falado no Brasil, geralmente por desconhecimento de regra, você ouvirá quase sempre:

> Eu não comprei bala nenhuma. *ou*
>   Eu não comprei nenhuma bala.

Você diz que "Fico com a impressão de que ao dizer, p.ex., que não tenho nenhum Real no bolso, isto implica que eu tenha dinheiro, já que o que não tenho é nenhum."

Na frase "Eu não tenho nenhum real no bolso" você pode entender a frase como se fosse "Eu não tenho nem um real no bolso". Assim, ao invés de trocar nenhum por "nada", você trocaria por "nem ao menos".

Sua frase ficaria: "Eu não tenho nem ao menos um real no bolso"